# ipconfig /flushdns permission in windows

Tags: windows, permissions

Is there a way way to allow permission to /flushdns in windows 7 or vista, to a certain user so even though he is not an administrator he can still do this and don't get this error?

```
The requested operation requires elevation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vista you can add the "network operator" role - that may include flushdns. Sadly, since 7 this seems to have gone AWOL :(

Comment: There is Network Configuration Operators group that I'm a member of, and it doesn't allow /flushdns

Comment: restart fixed the problem, it works

Comment: on 7? or just vista?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be to configure a scheduled task, running with an administrator as Log On account with elevation, and when the user needs to flush the cache, they simply go to task scheduler, right-click the task and select "Run now".

Normal users won't be able to modify the task without verifying the administrator credentials (it will prompt for password when they try to apply changes), so they cannot abuse your account for anything else

Answer (score 0):

I have heard (though not personally tested) that you can set these kinds of specific permissions using UAC (User Account Control) policies. Apparently they are actually much handier than we typically think (I often just disable it), but again I've not tried it...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that regmon from sysinternals might tell you what registry permissions are needed users to allow ipconfig /flushdns.

Offical Microsoft documentation mentions DNS related entries here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters
```

But several people have found in testing that the correct location for this entry should be:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```